# How to change the Dash Button in Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I don't like the default Dash Button (also known as **BFB** in short of *"Big Freakin Button"*) in Unity Launcher. It's pretty inconsistent with Faenza icon theme and I would like to change it. How can I do that?

[image: Dash Button in Unity Launcher]

Comment: We should merge these two together!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### 11.10

It is configurable. The unity icons are in /usr/share/unity/4. Please browse this folder with the file manager to see the thumbnails.

Here is an example to change the look of the default dash home:

```
cd /usr/share/unity/4
sudo mv squircle_base_54.png squircle_base_54.png.orig
sudo mv squircle_shine_54.png squircle_shine_54.png.orig
sudo cp round_outline_54x54.png squircle_base_54.png
sudo cp round_shine_54x54.png squircle_shine_54.png
```

Log out and log back in. You will see the new dash home.

[image]

Definitely more customization could be done as long as you replace the correct files. Please backup the original files before making the changes.

BTW, maybe you have the question: how do you know the solution? I hit the same problem and tried to search all related files:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "*dash*"
```

Comment: please add a link to a picture and I'll edit it into your answer for you.  Well done +1

Comment: Junjie W is right, in this folder if you replace launcher_bfb.png you replace the logo. It, may look like a transparent file but it is actually white with opacity. The background and edges are also in there.

Answer (score 8):

Steps to change unity dash icon:

1. Make your own icon 54x54 px
2. Save the new icon in a png format
3. Go to: `cd /usr/share/unity/4`
4. Make backup of the old icon: `sudo cp launcher_bfb.png launcher_bfb_def.png`
5. Delete the old icon: `sudo rm launcher_bfb.png`
6. Rename your new icon: `cp <yourIconName> launcher_bfb.png`
7. Move new icon in Unity: `sudo launcher_bfb.png /ust/share/unity/4`

here is my YouTube link: [How to change unity home dash icon ubuntu - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7-gSMWUsgY)

Answer (score 5):

### 12.04

In 12.04 the Unity 4 icons have changed completely:

There are these icons which build the Dash button:

```
squircle_base_54.png
squircle_base_selected_54.png
squircle_edge_54.png
squircle_glow_62.png
squircle_shadow_62.png
squircle_shine_54.png
```

And these which aren't used:

```
round_corner_54x54.png
round_glow_62x62.png
round_glow_hl_62x62.png
round_outline_54x54.png
round_shine_54x54.png
```

They are very different in size and name. I think you have to edit every squircle_ file yourself with an image editor like Gimp.

You can see for yourself: `nautilus /usr/share/unity/5/`

Answer (score 3):

## Ubuntu 13.04

> Get The Ubuntu Touch Feeling On The Unity Desktop With These Launcher Icons

1. To use the Ubuntu Touch Launcher icons / assets on the desktop (Unity), download the icons from [DeviantArt](http://aerilius.deviantart.com/art/Ubuntu-Touch-Launcher-icons-358618366) and extract the downloaded archive in your home folder.
2. Then, to replace the Unity icons with the Ubuntu Touch-style icons, use the following command:

   ```
   cd Downloads 

   unzip ubuntu_touch_launcher_icons_by_aerilius-d5xifpa.zip

   sudo cp -r unity/6 /usr/share/unity/
   ```

[image]

#### Reverting the changes

If you  revert the changes, simply reinstall unity-common using the following command:

```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-common
```

[Source Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/get-ubuntu-touch-feeling-on-unity.html)

Answer (score 3):

## Change the Ubuntu logo in Dash Button

If you wish to change only the Ubuntu *'Circle of Friends'* logo in Dash Button, just replace one of the following png files with another png icon of 128x128 size:

- `/usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_bfb.png` (for **Ubuntu 14.04LTS**'s *Unity 7.2*)
- `/usr/share/unity/5/launcher_bfb.png` (for **Ubuntu 12.04LTS**'s *Unity 5* and *Unity2D*)

[image: Change logo in Dash Button]
I made a logo pack with icons collected from various sources like icon packs ([Numix](https://numixproject.org), [Nitrux](https://nitrux.in), [Moka](http://samuelhewitt.com/moka/), [Faenza](https://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Faenza-Icons-173323228) and [Captiva](https://github.com/captiva-project/captiva-icon-theme)), Linux logo redesigns (by [Reda Lazri](https://github.com/0rAX0), [Dablim](https://dablim.deviantart.com) and [Nattapong Pullkhow](https://github.com/xenatt)), [official Ubuntu logos](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/ubuntu-logo), *Unity 7.2* and more. These logos are compatible with **Ubuntu 14.04LTS** *"Trusty Tahr"*'s Unity 7.2 and **Ubuntu 12.04LTS** *"Precise Pangolin"*'s Unity 5 and Unity2D. Should work with Unity 7.3 on newer releases like 15.04 *"Vivid Vervet"* and 15.10 *"Wily Werewolf"* too.

[image: Dash Button logos Preview]
[image: Download from DeviantArt]

---

## Change the whole Dash Button

### Ubuntu 16.04LTS

1. put the desired icon for the GTK theme, in your home: `~/.themes/$GTK_THEME/unity/launcher_bfb.svg`

   - `$GTK_THEME` can be `Numix`, or any other GTK theme you installed
   - do not have to copy - you may use a symlink (`ln -s $TARGET $SOURCE`)
   - I tried with `svg`, but a 128x128 `png` should also work.
2. Then use the tweak tool to change the GTK theme for the icon to refresh.
3. Enjoy!

### Ubuntu 14.04LTS

**Unity 7.2** introduced support for customizing *Unity Shell* via a new [Theming API](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming). **Dash Button** (also known as **BFB** in short of *"Big Freakin Button"*) is now treated the same as other Launcher buttons. So you can theme them all together by including the following files in the *unity* folder inside your current GTK theme:

```
$THEME_PATH/unity/launcher_icon_shadow_62.svg
$THEME_PATH/unity/launcher_icon_back_54.svg
$THEME_PATH/unity/launcher_icon_selected_back_54.svg
$THEME_PATH/unity/launcher_icon_edge_54.svg
$THEME_PATH/unity/launcher_icon_shine_54.svg
$THEME_PATH/unity/launcher_icon_glow_62.svg
```

You can either create new replacements for the above svg files or copy the *unity* folder from GTK themes that already implement Launcher theming ([Numix](https://launchpad.net/~numix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), [Moka Orchis](http://samuelhewitt.com/moka/download/orchis-gtk-theme), [Delorean Dark](https://github.com/killhellokitty/DeLorean-Dark-3.10-Ubuntu-14.04LTS) and [Ambiance Touch](https://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+Touch+for+Wily?content=174198) to name a few) and place it in any GTK theme in *~/.themes*. Now use an app like [Unity Tweak Tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unity-tweak-tool) and switch to the theme you modified.

### Ubuntu 12.04LTS

**Unity 5** doesn't have support for theming *Unity Dash* and *Launcher*. However, you can still alter it's appearance by replacing Unity's image assets. This is a hackish/modding method and isn't officially supported by Ubuntu. But it's the only easy way to modify Ubuntu 12.04LTS's Dash and Launcher. The **Dash Button** can be changed by replacing the following images in `/usr/share/unity/5`:

```
launcher_bfb.png
squircle_base_54.png
squircle_base_selected_54.png
squircle_edge_54.png
squircle_glow_62.png
squircle_shadow_62.png
squircle_shine_54.png
```

If you're unable to change the Dash Button by replacing these images, it's highly likely that your Ubuntu is running *Unity2D* desktop instead of *Unity*. **Unity2D** is a fallback desktop provided by Ubuntu 12.04LTS for low-end systems that cannot run the real Unity. Unfortunately, *Unity2D* doesn't use assets from `/usr/share/unity`, except for the BFB logo. To mod *Unity2D*, replace `/usr/share/unity/5/launcher_bfb.png` (for changing BFB logo/Dash Button logo) along with these files in `/usr/share/unity-2d/shell/launcher/artwork`:

```
squircle_base_54.png
squircle_base_selected_54.png
squircle_glow_54.png
squircle_shine_54.png
```

I made some Dash Button mods for Ubuntu 12.04LTS's Unity 5 and Unity2D using assets from Unity 7.2, [Aerilius's Ubuntu Touch mod for Unity 6](http://aerilius.deviantart.com/art/Ubuntu-Touch-Launcher-icons-358618366) and Ubuntu Touch SDK.

[image: Dash Button mods Preview]
[image: Download from DeviantArt]

Comment: Hey - do you know how could I enable the squircle on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? For some reason it's there - yet I don't know if I could use it.  I was going to ask this directly on the forum as a standalone question, but I thought you should probably know...

Comment: Hi @espectalll123 ! I know this is a (very) late reply, but I've updated my answer to cover **Ubuntu 14.04LTS** too. Hope this helps 

Answer (score 1):

The other methods here did not work for me. I found the easiest thing to do was to simply open the image in GIMP and edit it:

1. Open up the terminal
2. `sudo nautilus`
3. Go to`/usr/share/unity/icons`
4. Edit the image
5. Update it
6. Log out and back in.

Comment: Works on 14.04-3!

Comment: Work also on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove it as it is a part of the Unity Launcher code, Mark Shuttleworth explained the reasons behind the Dash icon and its place in the Launcher in his [blog post here](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/717).

Comment: I'm not trying to remove it, but to change it. I have read his blog post about Unity in Ubuntu 11.10 and it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Use Unity 2D - it is a lot more 'square' in that interface and matches the Faenza icon set better.

Answer (score 0):

The icons are at `/usr/share/unity/4/`. You can change them with your preferred png icons.

Reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7-gSMWUsgY

Comment: Hi! Welcome To AskUbuntu.. Please write your answer in text :D

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.