# Unity Dash Button

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-dash, icons, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the Dash icon in the Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68612/how-to-change-the-dash-icon-in-the-unity-launcher)

[How to change the Dash Button in Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68612/how-to-change-the-dash-icon-in-the-unity-launcher)

When I follow the instructions in the link above (yeah I know for 12.04 the directory must be changed to "5" from "4"), nothing happens when I log in.