# How do I change the software center icon in the launcher?

Tags: launcher, icons

I'm not a big fan of the Software Center icon (apparently I'm not the only one: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/software-centre-icon-proposal).

Is there a way change it?

The answers to this related question doesn't make it clear whether there is:
[How to change the Dash Button in Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68612/how-to-change-the-dash-icon-in-the-unity-launcher)

As far as I can see the Software Center icon isn't in `nautilus /usr/share/unity/5/` so where could it be?

Comment: I agree, that such a simple thing should be possible over a GUI as in any other OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal

`gksu  gedit /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-software-center.desktop`

Change `Icon=softwarecenter` to `Icon=/path/to/your/icon.png`  save