# How do you change the Dash icon in 13.04?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 13.04

Now I ask this and I consider it distinct in that the related question [How to change the Dash icon in the Unity Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68612/how-to-change-the-dash-icon-in-the-unity-launcher) is about old ubuntu versions like 11.10 this one is specifically for 13.04.