# How to modify unity icons

Tags: 13.04, icons

So I want to change couple of software icons for example "rhythmbox" I would like to change it's icon

can any one tell me where this software icons are stored and is it even possible to modify them without breaking the system

Thank you in advanced

Comment: please have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/68612/how-to-change-the-dash-icon-in-the-unity-launcher/286399#286399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icons are stored in `/usr/share/icons`.  You can edit these icons using [GNOME icon editor](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/gnome-iconedit).  But you can also download icon themes that you can install, and it will give a selection of different icons that you can use.

You can find these themes [here](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=120x121&PHPSESSID=b1a032cab7176dc5a1fcbf37fa57f04a)

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this post: -

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-customise-unity-like-never-before

also same problem related article:-

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)