# How to change the dash icon in Unity 15.04 to a custom .png?

Tags: 15.04, icons, unity-dash, customization, png

It's very tiring to have to keep looking at the default image of the Ubuntu logo in the dash. How do you change this default image into a custom image (btw, in my case I have a 48x48 `.png` ready to be changed to)?

Comment: The launcher icon to the top left? Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68612/how-to-change-the-dash-icon-in-the-unity-launcher). Basically replace the `launcher_bfb.png` file (as in step 10 here: http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/mbuntu-y-macbuntu-transformation-pack.html)

Comment: When I enter the first command in the terminal with the route of the `.png` I will replace the default one with in mind, I get a response saying `/home/flatenken/Downloads/launcher_bfb.png: Scheme missing.
` , What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which command did you use?

Comment: I used the command `wget -O launcher_bfb.png /home/flatenken/Downloads/launcher_bfb.png`, I assumed that using `/home/flatenken/Downloads/launcher_bfb.png` instead of `http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac-15.04/launcher-logo/apple/launcher_bfb.png` would do the same exact thing, but I guess it didn't. @isamert solved the problem, but I'm just updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your `launcher_bfb.png` to `/usr/share/unity/icons/`. In your case(I am assuming that your png file located in /home/flatenken/Downloads/launcher_bfb.png), you must give this command:

```
sudo mv /home/flatenken/Downloads/launcher_bfb.png /usr/share/unity/icons/
```